# How to make DTO property optional for json schema

Tags: c#, rest, jsonschema, dto

I have a DTO that has a property that is relevant only to the **GET** response.
In the **POST** request I don't need it - more than this - I **should not include it in the serialized json**.

So, I get this DTO as a response for the GET request and send it (without the mentioned property) in the Body when making a POST request.

Except for removing the optional property from the original class and locate it in a an inherited class - what other options do I have ? (using the JsonProperties, for example or other options)

This is my DTO:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    
    [JsonProperty("remark")]
    public string Remark {get; set;}
    
    [JsonProperty("optionalremark")] //relevant only to the GET request
    public string OptionalRemark {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Did you try this https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm

Comment: yes - no good -  there is no "not required"  value

Comment: @GuyE Could you please elaborate this: *I have a DTO that has a property that is relevant only to the GET request.* In case of GET you don't have request body, so where do you use this DTO?

Comment: I get this DTO as a response in the GET request and send it in the Body when making a  POST (added this remark it in the question)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways how you achieve that:

### Separate object

The most obvious choice could be to separate GET's response object from POST's request object. Most probably the two API can evolve independently. If any of these two changes then it requires modification on the DTO. You can use some sort of mapper (like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)) to define relationship between these two classes.

### Conditional Serialization

Newtonsoft does support [conditional seralization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm). All you have to do is to define a method which returns a `bool` and is named like `ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}`:

```cs
public class MyDTO
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    
    [JsonProperty("remark")]
    public string Remark {get; set;}
    
    [JsonProperty("optionalremark")]
    public string OptionalRemark {get; set;}
    
    public bool ShouldSerializeOptionalRemark() => false;
}
```

This method is called only during serialization. So, deserialization works as expected.

### ContractResolver

If you don't want to include a `ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}` method into your DTO then you can place this logic inside a custom `ContractResolver`:

```cs
public class MyDTOContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(MyDTO) && property.PropertyName == nameof(MyDTO.OptionalRemark).ToLower())
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = _ => false;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

You can specify this resolver for `SerializeObject` and `DeserializeObject` as well:

```cs
var getResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDTO>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyDTOContractResolver() });

var postRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyDTOContractResolver() });
```

During deserialization it does not have any affect. So, if you need to you can register this resolver globally as well:

```cs
services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(opts =>
{
    opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new MyDTOContractResolver();
});
```

This code works in ASP.NET Core 3.x or higher projects. In case of older ASP.NET Core project, please use `AddJsonOptions` instead of `AddNewtonsoftJson`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, You can use `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on you DTO property, like this:-

```
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
public List<SomethingDTO> something_dto { get; set; }
```